# Add value to one column in query results

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a query in a spreadsheet:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(swgohEventsCal!$A$2:$D,"SELECT A,B,C where A contains 'TB' and C >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' order by B limit 4", 0),"Nothing Scheduled!")
```

Column B displays a date and time, but the time defaults to 12 AM.  What I would like to do is add 24 hours, or one day, to that time.

So when the result is `5/26/2019 0:00:00`, I would like for it to display `5/27/2019 0:00:00`.

[here's my spreadsheet for reference](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H3_dewOBc_kYzBkkUzT2odis1cndgvHkRAjGadl2XOk/edit#gid=463235001&range=A3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY(
 {swgohEventsCal!$A$2:$A,swgohEventsCal!$B$2:$B+1,swgohEventsCal!$C$2:$D},
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3 
  where Col1 contains 'TB' 
    and Col3 >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
  order by Col2 
  limit 4", 0), "Nothing Scheduled!"))
```

[image: 0]